# Alternative to scraping netstat for getting list of remote IP addresses?

Tags: python, monitoring, ipv6, pexpect, netstat

I'm currently scraping the output of `netstat -n -A inet` on Linux and `netstat -n -f inet` on Mac OSX to get a collection of remote IP addresses and ports to which the machine is connected using the following (Python default) regex:

```
'(?:[0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+[.:][0-9]+\s+((?:[0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+)[.:]([0-9]+)'
```

This gives me the remote IP in group 1 and the remote port in group 2.

However, this doesn't seem portable or maintainable (and is limited to IPv4 addresses).

Is there a better alternative to getting a list of active remote IPs?

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is always SNMP... The full TCP connection table is at `.1.3.6.1.2.1.6.19` (also known as .iso.org.dod.internet.mgmt.mib-2.tcp.tcpConnectionTable) and the full UDP table is at  `.1.3.6.1.2.1.7.7` (also known as .iso.org.dod.internet.mgmt.mib-2.udp.udpEndpointTable).

Here is an example of my local Linux box:

```
$ snmpbulkwalk -v2c -c xxxx -m ALL 83.137.17.100 .iso.org.dod.internet.mgmt.mib-2.tcp.tcpConnectionTable
TCP-MIB::tcpConnectionState.ipv4."83.137.17.100".44463.ipv4."91.189.89.90".80 = INTEGER: timeWait(11)
TCP-MIB::tcpConnectionState.ipv4."83.137.17.100".44470.ipv4."91.189.89.90".80 = INTEGER: timeWait(11)
TCP-MIB::tcpConnectionState.ipv6."00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:ff:ff:53:89:11:64".80.ipv6."00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:ff:ff:53:55:f2:7b".51612 = INTEGER: timeWait(11)
TCP-MIB::tcpConnectionState.ipv6."00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:ff:ff:53:89:11:64".80.ipv6."00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:ff:ff:53:55:f2:7b".51622 = INTEGER: timeWait(11)
TCP-MIB::tcpConnectionState.ipv6."00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:ff:ff:53:89:11:64".80.ipv6."00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:ff:ff:53:55:f2:7b".51623 = INTEGER: timeWait(11)
TCP-MIB::tcpConnectionState.ipv6."00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:ff:ff:53:89:11:64".80.ipv6."00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:ff:ff:53:55:f2:7b".51624 = INTEGER: finWait2(7)
TCP-MIB::tcpConnectionState.ipv6."00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:ff:ff:53:89:11:64".80.ipv6."00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:ff:ff:53:f7:0a:da".59728 = INTEGER: timeWait(11)
TCP-MIB::tcpConnectionState.ipv6."20:01:40:38:00:00:00:16:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:16".22.ipv6."2a:00:86:40:00:01:00:00:54:f4:06:96:6c:48:aa:a9".49644 = INTEGER: established(5)
TCP-MIB::tcpConnectionProcess.ipv4."83.137.17.100".44463.ipv4."91.189.89.90".80 = Gauge32: 0
TCP-MIB::tcpConnectionProcess.ipv4."83.137.17.100".44470.ipv4."91.189.89.90".80 = Gauge32: 0
TCP-MIB::tcpConnectionProcess.ipv6."00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:ff:ff:53:89:11:64".80.ipv6."00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:ff:ff:53:55:f2:7b".51612 = Gauge32: 0
TCP-MIB::tcpConnectionProcess.ipv6."00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:ff:ff:53:89:11:64".80.ipv6."00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:ff:ff:53:55:f2:7b".51622 = Gauge32: 0
TCP-MIB::tcpConnectionProcess.ipv6."00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:ff:ff:53:89:11:64".80.ipv6."00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:ff:ff:53:55:f2:7b".51623 = Gauge32: 0
TCP-MIB::tcpConnectionProcess.ipv6."00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:ff:ff:53:89:11:64".80.ipv6."00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:ff:ff:53:55:f2:7b".51624 = Gauge32: 0
TCP-MIB::tcpConnectionProcess.ipv6."00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:ff:ff:53:89:11:64".80.ipv6."00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:ff:ff:53:f7:0a:da".59728 = Gauge32: 0
TCP-MIB::tcpConnectionProcess.ipv6."20:01:40:38:00:00:00:16:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:16".22.ipv6."2a:00:86:40:00:01:00:00:54:f4:06:96:6c:48:aa:a9".49644 = Gauge32: 0
```

The Net-SNMP tools make the output a little bit more readable. In numerical form the first output line would be:

```
1.3.6.1.2.1.6.19.1.7.1.4.83.137.17.100.44463.1.4.91.189.89.90.80 = INTEGER: 11
```

Or in fully expanded text:

```
.iso.org.dod.internet.mgmt.mib-2.tcp.tcpConnectionTable.tcpConnectionEntry.tcpConnectionState.ipv4."83.137.17.100".44463.ipv4."91.189.89.90".80
```

I'm not sure if this is any easier than what you are doing now, but it *is* a standardised way...

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of SNMP. There does happen to be a Python interface [PySNMP](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

If you're not scared of C and U*X internals you could reverse engineer netstat.

Take a look here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21503/source-code-of-netstat

Comment: I've considered it, and I may do just that.